# Reading UTF-8 file and writing plain ANSI?

Tags: java

I have an UTF-8 file (it's a csv).
I need to read line by line this file do some replace and then write line by line into another file.

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(fileFix), "ASCII")
    );
    bw.write("");   //clean current file


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file),"UTF-8")
    );

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.replace(";", ",");
        bw.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

Simple as that.
The problem is that the output file (fileFix) is UTF-8 and i think it has the BOM character.

How can I write the file as plain ANSI without the BOM?

The error I am getting while reading my file with a software (weka)

[image]

The first line of this file:

[image]

Consider that notepad++ tells me the charset is UTF-8. If i try to convert this file in plain ASCII (with windows notepad), that chars disappers

### Solution

When you are on the first line run:

```
line = line.substring(1);
```

To remove any BOM char.

Comment: What do you want to happen to any characters which aren't in whichever ANSI encoding you mean? (And which one *do* you mean?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't use any "exoctic" chars. My input file has standard `A-Z0-9;,.`

Comment: The problem is when I open my output file with a software (weka) the first char appears to be something strange. If i save this file with notepad and ANSI charset the problem is solved

Comment: I suspect you mean ASCII or ISO-8869-1 encoding? If you don't use any exotic characters UTF-8 is the same as ASCII 7 bit.

Comment: Your code will remove the first character of *any* file. That means if it doesn't start with a BOM, you're going to lose data. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No because i will not use this script with any file, but just with this kind of file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this is a BOM issue rather than an encoding issue as such.

You can just remove any BOM characters as you write the file, with:

```
line = line.replace("\ufeff", "");
```

That leaves the question of whether you're reading the data accurately in the first place... I'd *strongly* advise you not to use `FileWriter` and `FileReader` at all - instead, use `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`, specifying the encoding explicitly for both of them. Set the reader encoding to UTF-8 (assuming the input file really is UTF-8), and set the writer encoding to whatever you want... but I'd recommend sticking with UTF-8, to be honest.

Also note that you should be closing your reader/writer in `finally` blocks, or using the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement if you're using Java 7.

Comment: thanks I will try that. Also I have edited my question I have added some explanation pics

Comment: Also... Should I add that replace within the first loop of my while?

Comment: @yes123: Might as well - you're very unlikely to see the character elsewhere, but it wouldn't do any harm.

Comment: I have tried your replace. didn't worked. that chars (as shown in figure) is still there. The only way I have to fix this is Open notepad, choose "save as" and select charset: "ansi"

Comment: Maybe there is some initial "hidden" char in my input file (UTF-8) and I can't see it. But as you can see notepad++ doesnt' show nothing before "id"

Comment: ps. I have fixed your typo "InputStreamWriter"

Comment: @JonSkeet I think that it is the wrong pattern to replace that's an utf-16 bom according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @Konstantin: By the time it's been read, it *is* in UTF-16. Giving the *binary* version isn't a good idea.

Comment: @yes123: If you set the encoding appropriately (as per the second part of my answer, using `InputStreamReader`) my answer *will* work, if it's really UTF-8. It's important to understand the difference between the *binary* representation, and the *character* (U+FEFF) it represents.

Comment: @jon: I have tried InputStreamReader (as you can see I have edited the question) and your replace still doesn't work. I feel more confortable to use substring(1) because I know my input file will have the BOM.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct disregard my comment, I forgot that java is using UTF-16 to represent strings. Your solution works just fine (given an UTF-8 file as input)

Comment: @yes123: It really, really should work. Can you print out the value of `(int) line.charAt(0)`?

Comment: @Jon: I don't understand 1 thing: why if I open the file with UTF-8 you make me search for UTF-16 BOM ? Even if java uses internally UTF-16 should that char stay EF BB BF ?

Comment: And... why I get 65279 if wikipedia says UTF-16 BOM decimal is : 254'255  (losing my mind :S)

Comment: @yes123: When you read a file (which is in bytes) you specify an encoding. That converts the data into UTF-16 code units, regardless of original encoding... because that's what Java uses to store text. 65279 = 0xfeff, i.e. 0xfe, 0xff = 254, 255. It's not "two hundred and fifty-four thousand, two hundred and fifty-five".

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark for the pattern to replace, looks like     EF BB BF rather than    FE FF

**This solution is wrong** check Jons answer intsead

Comment: If you look at the UTF-8 you can see there is the BOM! `ï»¿` This is really the char I am getting

Comment: I have tried this line, but with no luck `line = line.replace("\uefbbbf", "");` that char is still there

Comment: I have found the solution, when you are on teh first line:    `line = line.substring(1);`

Comment: No, this is meant to be replacing the *character* U+FEFF. If the OP sets the encoding correctly for input, my solution should work fine. EF BB BF is the set of *bytes* to replace. The code isn't reading bytes - it's reading characters. Using `line.substring(1)` is just avoiding the issue of using the right encoding to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I can't know which is the correct charset of input file **but** I know there will be the BOM

Comment: @yes123 If the first character has the value '65279' (check with a debugger )then JonSkeet's solution works

Comment: @Konstantin: I have tried: `line = line.replace("\ufeff", "");` with no luck really